# Return a pointer to an array from a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

There is the question problem: "Implement a function to receive a vector of vectors representing a square array of integers
and to return a pointer to a 1-D Run-Time array containing a copy (row by row) of the upper diagonal elements."
Here is what I did so far and please excuse for any mistakes as this my first time posting here  :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
const int N = 4;
int * pointer(vector<vector<int>>amatrix)
{
    int L = (N*N - N) / 2;
    int * b;
    b = new int[L];
        for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j < N; j++)
            {
                int c = amatrix[i][j];
                for (int k = 0; k < (N*N - N) / 2; k++)
                    b[k] = c;
            }
    return b;
}
void main()
{
    vector<vector<int>>amatrix(N, vector<int>(N));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            amatrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << amatrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < (N*N - N) / 2; i++)
        cout << pointer(amatrix)[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: And your question is?...

Comment: What is the question? If you don't have a specific problem, this is off-topic. You may want to get your question moved to codereview? Don't repost though, ask an admin to do that

Comment: @Upvoters: Please consider leaving a comment why you upvoted this _"question"_!

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing, Seems like people have 20 different accounts and upvotes their own shit

Comment: `Implement a function to receive a vector of vectors representing a square array of integers and to return a pointer to a 1-D Run-Time array containing a copy (row by row) of the upper diagonal elements.`  An idiotic assignment.  If you're going to use `std::vector` you use it all the way, not piecemeal.  Your code now has a gigantic memory leak.

Comment: Does this code work as you want it to or not? If it does, I can recommend Code Review. If it does not, you should ask about a specific problem and keep it on Stack Overflow. If you are unsure, then you should test the code before you post it anywhere.

Comment: @nilo If there's any proof for such, that question and user account should be flagged for moderator attention, and the account(s) should be killed/banned.

Answer (score 0):

Catch! :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int * pointer( const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &amatrix )
{
    size_t n = amatrix.size();
    size_t size = ( n * n - n ) / 2;

    int *p = new int[size];
    int *q = p;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ ) *q++ = amatrix[i][j];
    }        

    return p;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 4;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> amatrix( N, std::vector<int>( N ) );

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( 0 ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) amatrix[i][j] = std::rand() % 10;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) std::cout << amatrix[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int *p = pointer( amatrix );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < ( N * N - N ) / 2; i++ ) std::cout << p[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete []p;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
6 3 4 7 
6 0 1 2 
9 9 7 8 
8 8 4 4 

3 4 7 1 2 8
```

As for your code then this loop in the function

```
            for (int k = 0; k < (N*N - N) / 2; k++)
                b[k] = c;
```

does not make sense.

Also there is no sense to call the function for each iteration of the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < (N*N - N) / 2; i++)
    cout << pointer(amatrix)[i] << " ";
```

because there will be memory leaks because the function each time when it is called allocates a new array.

Comment: Don't use `std::rand()` or `std::strand(...)` they're broken.

Comment: @Casey What do you mean?

Comment: @Casey  I am sorry but i am not going to read this. If you think that there is a problem with std::srand() or std:;rand you can send your defect report to the C++ Standards Committee.